# How to preload nextjs images in the previous page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-images

I am trying to preload images located in the public/assets/images directory in Next.js 13.
But it is not likely to use the import someImg from '../../'; because I want to display one of the images using the query data, like this:

```js
<Image src={data.onlineClassImageURL} />
```

I've tried priority option, and  but it does not worked properly.(it is slower than I expected) I want the images to be displayed as quickly as if the user had already downloaded them. How can I implement this?